# Is GET or SET defined in class

Tags: javascript, class, properties, getter-setter, exists

I try to find out, if the current derived class has a property setter. Reason is that I loop a couple of options through the constructors of extended classes. and just want to assign those properties, that are part of this class and not the base class.

So I need a possibility to find out, if the getter or setter exist for this class or not. I remove as much code as possible to show case the issue only.

This is the base class:

```
class baseClass{
    constructor(wOptions){
        //do some stuff
        if(typeof wOptions == "object"){
            for(let prop in wOptions){
                // if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop) != undefined){
                // if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop) != undefined){ /* doesn't work either */
                if(typeof this[prop] != "undefined"){ /* calls the getter, if exists.  */
                    this[prop] = wOptions[prop];
                    delete wOptions[prop];
                } 
            }
        }       
    }
    get mainProperty(){
        return 42;
    }
    set mainProperty(newValue){
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Here is the the derived class:

```
class derivatedClass extends baseClass{
    constructor(wOptions){
        super(wOptions)
        //do some other stuff 
        let html = document.body;
        Object.defineProperty(this, "html", {value: html, writable: false});

        if(typeof wOptions == "object"){
            for(let prop in wOptions){
                // if(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(this, prop) != undefined){
                // if(this.hasOwnProperty(prop) != undefined){ /* doesn't work either */
                if(typeof this[prop] != "undefined"){ /* calls the getter, if exists.  */
                    this[prop] = wOptions[prop];
                    delete wOptions[prop];
                } 
            }
        }       
    }
    get otherProperty(){
        return html.innerText;
    }
    set otherProperty(newValue){
        return html.innerText = newValue;
    }
}
```

And how to initialize the object:

```
let options = {otherProperty: "new Text"};
let object = new derivatedClass(options);
console.log(options);
```

Regarding the solutions tried already:

- `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` always returns `undefined`; returns the `options` as assigned
- `hasOwnProperty` always returns `false` ; returns the `options` as assigned
- `typeof this[prop] != "undefined"` calls the getter and this can be pretty bad, because html is not defined yet. Reference Error for `html.innerText`
- Not a solution, but for verification: Removing the `if` clause in the derived class, changes the body text to `new Text` and prints an empty object in the console.

Tested in Chrome 71.

There would be some options to avoid this:

- shift all properties handled by this class to another object (pretty ugly and high possibility to forget a property in the list)
- use always `Object.defineProperty`, because they will be executed after the `super` call. However, it is not that pretty than the get/set functions of the class construct.

Is there any possibility to find out if there is a setter available for `otherProperty`, that evaluates true in the derivatedClass but not in the baseClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(derivatedClass.prototype, 'otherProperty');
console.log(descriptor);
```

If `derivatedClass.prototype` has an `otherProperty` (otherwise returns `undefined`), it will return an object that contains some values. In the returned object, you should see `get` and `set`

[More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor)

Comment: `const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(derivatedClass.prototype, prop)
if(descriptor !== undefined && typeof descriptor.set == "function")`  
works for me!